# sqlalchemy psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege: permission denied for relation <<table>>

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, permissions

I've read over 20 different questions with the same problem - and the suggested answers didn't solve my problem. I'm still getting `sqlalchemy psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege: permission denied for relation <<table>>`

Environment: EC2, debian 8, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy
my table in postgresql:

```
Create table Members(
id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
joinDate TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT Now(),
password TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

directly in postgresql: `INSERT INTO members (password) VALUES('123')  RETURNING id;` works perfect

I've granted my user all possible grants

```
grant all privileges on database <my_db> to <my_user>
grant all privileges on all table in schema public to <my_user>
grant all privileges on all relations in schema public to <my_user>
```

I've also created a `.htaccess` file under `var/www/html` with `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

my table mapped with sqlalchemy `member.py`

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from sqlalchemy.schema import UniqueConstraint
import sqlalchemy as sa

Engine = create_engine('postgresql://<my_user>:<my_psw>@<my_db_url>/<my_dn_name>')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=Engine)
Base = declarative_base()

class MemberSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Number()    
    password = fields.Str()

class Member(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'members'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    password = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, password):
        self.password = password
```

the code receiving the POST and doing the insert in `test.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import logging

def register_member(password):
    session = Session()
    newMember = Member(password)
    session.add(newMember)
    session.commit()
    return newMember

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@cross_origin()    
def register():
    try:
        formData = request.form
        register_member(formData['password'])
        return jsonify({"message":"Regsitrated successfully!"})
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.debug(ex)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1234, debug=True)
```

executing this code results in exception with these errors

```
DEBUG:root:(psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege) permission denied for relation members

[SQL: INSERT INTO members (password) VALUES (%(password)s) RETURNING members.id]
[parameters: {'password': '4444'}]
```

and

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: out of curiosity, did you ever figure this out? Running into the same thing right now :P

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if you're manually testing with `psql` or `pgAdmin`, but ensure you're testing with the same account used in your code.

Even if the user has access to a table/relation in the schema, they also need access to the schema itself:
`grant usage on schema public to <myuser>`

Also, I noticed use of `BIGSERIAL` which involves a sequence.  You'll probably need a `grant usage on all sequences in schema public to <myuser>`.

Answer (score 9):

It appears there are several layers of privileges in a PostgreSQL database. If one layer is missing the privilege, the query fails.

1. Database: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE thedatabse TO theotheruser;`
2. Each schema
3. Each table
4. Each sequence

for layers 2-4 it depends on the structure of the database but regardless of the structure it would involve quite a bit of typing and/or clicking to change privileges for each item in each of these layers or a complex query.

Comment: This worked for me, for some reason the permissions were at the table level and step 3 fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me too. Although I did go also add permissions on the schema too, but it seems that's not the key according to @Eric

Comment: Yep, it was step 4 for me, the primary key's auto-increment used a sequence. Anyway, to get people started:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user;`
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO user;`

Comment: postres has as burdensome system of privileges. not at all user friendly. especially for those coming from mysql

Answer (score 2):

if you are in a situation like me i.e. you are facing this issue after running 'airflow db migrate' command to setup postgresql as backend database for airflow and below is the configuration you have defined in your Airflow.cfg

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://xuser:xpass@localhost:5432/xdb
```

then for some reason, I have run all Grant permissions but in the end its this ALTER query which did the trick for me, and I came across this issue twice and both times, this query did it for me. (given that you have already run all Grant queries mentioned in this thread. then give the below one a try as well.

```
ALTER DATABASE xdb OWNER TO xuser;
```

Comment: I also has to do the alter command after some db migration...

Answer (score 1):

This is the query i've generated using Grant Wizard in PgAdmin that finally worked for me to use the DB with psycopg2:

```sql
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.table1 TO <username>;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.table2 TO <username>;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.table3 TO <username>;
```

You can try to install PgAdmin and use the same tool as well, it works fine.

Comment: just be aware that if you are deploying on a production environment, make sure that grant all for a particular user is what you really want, and that this user is safe from outside threats

Answer (score -2):

run the following SQL in the PgAdmin or phpAdmin, whichever you are using,

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE table_name TO user_name;

GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO user_name;
```

Answer (score -3):

Granting privileges to the user will not work, just create the tables with the same user whose credentials you've provided on the Flask/Django settings.

This is how it worked for me, I know I'm late but hope this helps.